# Reloading images on another form

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I have a form which has an image on, The user has an option to click an edit button to change the image. This opens up another form (Is important it opens on another form). The user selects the image and saves it etc.

Now when I try to update/reload the form The image does not change.

I can refresh the image from the same form. But cannot refresh the image from another form.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtParamater.Text))
{
    StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(rootDirectory + "\\slot\\" + slot.Text.ToString() + ".txt", true); // save name and file location
    sw1.WriteLine(txtStartProgram.Text.ToString());

    MessageBox.Show("Your image has been updated", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    sw1.Close();
    MainForm dsh = new MainForm();
    this.Close();
    dsh.FormRefresh();
}
```

dsh.FormRefresh, provides a method which re-updates the picture box, however picture box does not reload from the second form. But works on the same form.

Comment: post your code for clarity if possible

Answer (score 0):

You just created a **new instance** of the original form here:

```
MainForm dsh = new MainForm();
this.Close();
dsh.FormRefresh();
```

What you need to do is, open the form to change the image as a modal, or send in the current instance of this form as a parameter.

Here is an example: [C# exchanging values between forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397398/c-sharp-exchanging-values-between-forms/21397518#21397518)